How to add color based on a column with string values for parallel categories chart in plotly?
For the plotly demo code of Multi-Color Parallel Categories Diagram, it was using a column with integer values to define color, i.e. the “Survived” column in the titanic data set.
color = titanic_df.Survived;
colorscale = [[0, 'lightsteelblue'], [1, 'mediumseagreen']];

fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Parcats(dimensions=[class_dim, gender_dim, survival_dim],
        line={'color': color, 'colorscale': colorscale},
        hoveron='color', hoverinfo='count+probability',
        labelfont={'size': 18, 'family': 'Times'},
        tickfont={'size': 16, 'family': 'Times'},
        arrangement='freeform')])


However, if I changed it to use a column with string values, I got the following error:

code changed:

color = titanic_df.Sex
colorscale = [
    ['male', 'blue'],
    ['female', 'orange'],
]


Error:

ValueError: 
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'color' property of p
arcats.line
        Invalid elements include: ['male', 'female', 'female'
, 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female
']

    The 'color' property is a color and may be specified as: 
      - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
      - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
      - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
      - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
      - A named CSS color:
...

So, I’d like to ask how to specify the color of a parallel categories chart based on a column with string values.
